# Imagemagick command in php does not work correctly

Tags: php

I have a PHP script, in which I can set the parameters for imagemagick

I want to use this command

```
convert image.jpg -distort SRT  "%[fx:aa=14*pi/180;(w*abs(sin(aa))+h*abs(cos(aa)))/min(w,h)], 14" rotate_image.jpg
```

In the script I set this command

```
-distort SRT  "%[fx:aa=14*pi/180;(w*abs(sin(aa))+h*abs(cos(aa)))/min(w,h)], 14"
```

But this command doesn't work.

I think there's a problem with `"` or `=` in my command

For instance, if I test this command

```
-enhance -sharpen 1x1 -quality 90 -strip
```

It works fine.

Comment: I not have source code PHP script, i have only setting options, where i can set imagemagick string.

Comment: In this case its hard to say what can cause a problem, because we don't know how the string with options is sanitized.

Comment: Try replacing the double quotes with single ones as there is nothing in the string that you need the shell to expand. And try adding a single quote as the second character and another as the second-to-last character of the existing string.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `php`?

Comment: In bash imagemagick command work good, but in php script not work.

Comment: Above you explain you have no php code. Then what does not work? Please post your php code. We need to see if you try to use the imagick php extension or to execute the command as a separate process, for example. So how do you use imagemagick?

Comment: php not correct understand imagemagick string with ",=,%,

Comment: You did not really answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say how you try to use imagick from within php. From your wording I would guess that you try to execute the cli executable via some form of `exec()` call. This is possible, the following code works as expected for me and rotates the image:

```
<?php
$command = "convert image.jpg -distort SRT '%[fx:aa=14*pi/180;(w*abs(sin(aa))+h*abs(cos(aa)))/min(w,h)], 14' rotate_image.jpg";
exec($command);
```

Note however that usually it is a good idea to prefer a php extension over an `exec()` call. Less security issues, less hassle with argument interpretation by the spawned shell (as in this case) and easier debugging. There is an image magick extension for php. Using that you have all commands available as functions right within php itself.